# Номера страниц в пагинации

Tags: php, pagination

Есть страница со статьями. Нужно сделать пагинацию. На странице должно быть 10 статей.
Сделал пагинацию - всё работает. Нужно сделать номера страниц. Столкнулся с проблемой. Для тестового варианта было сделано 25 статей. Тобишь должно быть 3 страницы в виде цифр. У меня получается 2.
Код такой:

```
<div class="pagination">
<div class="page_prev" style="display: none">Prev</div>
<div class="pages_icons clearfix">
    <? if (count($listingData) != 0) { ?>
        <? $indx =0; $page = 1;?>
        <? for($i = 0; $i <= count($listingData); $i++) { ?>
            <? if($indx === $max_per_page) { ?>
                <?$indx = 0;?>
                <div class="page_icon <?echo ($page === 1) ? "active" : "" ;?>" data-page-icon="<?=$page;?>"><?=$page;?></div>
                <?$page++;?>
            <? } else { $indx++; }?>
        <? } ?>
    <? } ?>
</div>
<div class="page_next">Next</div>
```

Как сделать что бы оставшиеся 5 (как в этом примере) считались как 3-яя страница?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужна функция [ceil](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ceil.php)

> ceil — Округляет дробь в большую сторону

```
<div class="pagination">
<div class="page_prev" style="display: none">Prev</div>
<div class="pages_icons clearfix">
<? $page_count = ceil(count($listingData) / $max_per_page); ?>
<? for($page = 1; $page <= $page_count; ++$page) : ?>
    <div class="page_icon <?echo ($page === 1) ? "active" : "" ;?>" data-page-icon="<?=$page;?>"><?=$page;?></div>
<? endfor; ?>
</div>
<div class="page_next">Next</div>
```